# Jpa Specification search like in a composed field

Tags: spring, postgresql, jpa, specifications

I have an Entity class and also a JPARepository:

```
@Entity
class MyClass(){
Integer id;
String type;
String coin;
}
```

and in my service I create and return another model class which has a String param:

```
class ResponseClass(){
String txId;
}

txId = String.format(myModel, type.chartAt(0),coin.chartAt(0), new MyClass().getId())
```

I returned to controller `new ResponseClass().setTxId(txId)`

How can I make a query which search in my table after txId value? I have to use JPA Specification.

Example of table:

```
ID  Type    Coin
001 Deposit USD
```

and my is txID = DU-001. I want to search in the table after this composed value and return the entry!

Comment: How are you connecting to the database? After you set `txId`, you can connect to the database, can you not? Any chance seeing more code or what you have tried?

Comment: @aksappy I tried to split the txId in 3 parts and search in all 3 fields with every individual part, but is very ugly and should build a complex algorithm for it. I guess there should be something easier then that.

Comment: static Specification<Todo>fieldContainsIgnoreCase(String searchTerm) {
        return (root, query, cb) -> {
            String containsLikePattern = getContainsLikePattern(searchTerm);
            return cb.or(
                    cb.like(cb.lower(root.<String>get(MyClass_.id)), containsLikePattern),
                    cb.like(cb.lower(root.<String>get(MyClass_.type)), containsLikePattern),cb.like(cb.lower(root.<String>get(MyClass_.coin)), containsLikePattern)
            );
        };
    }.